# Navigating to other page clicking on a image passing values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am new to .NET/ JS . I have an .aspx page where we will have to navigate to other page when clicking on the image on the table.So while clicking(or navigating to the other page) we will have to pass the values from other columns of the same row we are clicking.

So the Table has the columns like 
[image]
So the Action has the icon which will be navigating to  the other page. But I will need to pass the Task Name and Last Run values along.Currently I did

```
   function dataReview_tasks(obj) {
        var i = 0;
        var data_FileKeys = new Array();
        $('.chkImport')
            .each(function (index, value) {
                if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                    var info = new IOInfo(this);
                    data_FileKeys[i] = info.key(0);
                    i++;
                }
            });
           window.location = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/GUI/DataReviewNEW.aspx") %>';
    }
```

I understand we can pass values as ?col1=values but not sure how would we can make them as the values from the table.Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: An alternative: Put the table in a form, use form elements, post the form and redirect from the method.   Also, hard to tell what you want as your text says 'columns of the same row we are clicking' but the code says 'all checkboxes'.

Comment: @freedomn-m I tried to replicate the replicate the from the other page. I cannot change the table structure, is it possible to get only the column name like TaskName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the table store values for every row in data attribute of anchor tag (action with icon) if you don't want the id to be visible on screen. 
[image: for example]
As in above image you can see the edit button which upon click will redirect to another page allowing to edit the information. Following is the generated html of that anchor.

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit" class="btnWorkstationEdit Pointer" data-workstationid="70062"></a>
```

Now in order to get the id in jquery you can probably do something like

```
function dataReview_tasks(obj) {       
    $('.btnWorkstationEdit').click(function{
             window.location = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/GUI/DataReviewNEW.aspx?"'+$(this).attr('data-workstationid')+'"") %>';
     });            
}
```